# What the proper way to call async on DataServiceQuery

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await

I am following this example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756367(v=vs.110).aspx

but i modified it to look like this

```
      public static void BeginExecuteCustomersQuery()
      {
         DataServiceQuery<ASHPersonify.OrderDetailInfo> query = 
        (DataServiceQuery<ASHPersonify.OrderDetailInfo>)
        (SvcClient.Ctxt.OrderDetailInfos
         .Where(a =>a.ShipMasterCustomerId == "pppp" 
                && a.ShipSubCustomerId == 0
                && a.LineStatusCode == "A"));

                try
                {
                    query.BeginExecute(OnCustomersQueryComplete, query);
                }
                catch (DataServiceQueryException ex)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(
                        "An error occurred during query execution.", ex);
                }
         }


       public List<ASHPersonify.OrderDetailInfo> OnCustomersQueryComplete(IAsyncResult result)
       {
                // Get the original query from the result.
                DataServiceQuery<ASHPersonify.OrderDetailInfo> query =
                    result as DataServiceQuery<ASHPersonify.OrderDetailInfo>;

               return query.EndExecute(result).ToList();

        }
```

and now I am getting this error:

> `System.Collections.Generic.List<ASH_QIS.ASHPersonify.OrderDetailInfo>`  has the wrong return type

on this line:

```
query.BeginExecute(OnCustomersQueryComplete, query);
```

what is the proper way and if it possible to implement something like this.

Comment: May there be an explanation why there is -2

Answer (score 3):

Based on [the signature of `BeginExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646858), `OnCustomersQueryComplete` has to be convertible to [`AsyncCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback), which means its return type has to be `void`. This pattern is called [the Asynchronous Programming Model or APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963).

I don't know how do you expect to work with the result, but I think the best option, if you can use C# 5.0 is to use `async`-`await` and [`Task.Factory.FromAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync):

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteAsync<T>(this DataServiceQuery<T> query)
{
    return Task.Factory.FromAsync(query.BeginExecute, query.EndExecute, null);
}

…

public static Task<IEnumerable<ASHPersonify.OrderDetailInfo>> ExecuteCustomersQueryAsync()
{
    var query = 
        (DataServiceQuery<ASHPersonify.OrderDetailInfo>)
        (SvcClient.Ctxt.OrderDetailInfos
            .Where(a =>a.ShipMasterCustomerId == "pppp" 
                && a.ShipSubCustomerId == 0
                && a.LineStatusCode == "A"));

    try
    {
        return await query.ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (DataServiceQueryException ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(
            "An error occurred during query execution.", ex);
    }
}
```